# JSch can't connect via Kerberos keytab file

Tags: ssh, kerberos, jsch, jaas, keytab

I built a Java application, which runs a command via ssh. In the first attempt I authenticated via username and password, and everything worked fine.

Now I want to use a Kerberos keytab file to make the authentication, but this makes problems!

Here a few words to my configuration:

- KDC server: `my-server.de`
- Realm name: `MYREALM.DE`
- Keytab username: `keytabuser`
- KDC = server: runs on `CentOS 7`
- my client: `Windows 8.1 (x64)` with all default configurations, `Kerberos for Windows` installed
- my username on client: `Daniel`
- `kinit -kt ...` seems to work fine, so the keytab file should also be ok

What I have so far is this code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "my-server.de";
        String user = "keytabuser";
        String  command = "ls -l";

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.setLogger(new MyLogger());

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\ProgramData\\MIT\\Kerberos5\\krb5.ini");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\ProgramData\\MIT\\Kerberos5\\jaas.conf");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

        //to enable kerberos debugging mode
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

        try {
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "gssapi-with-mic");

            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect(20000);

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ... // Do the commands

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This is my `jaas.conf` file:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  doNotPrompt=true
  principal="keytabuser@MYREALM.DE"
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\keytabuser.keytab"
  storeKey=true;
};
```

And here my `krb5.ini` file:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = MYREALM.DE

[realms]
  MYREALM.DE = {
    admin_server = my-server.de
    kdc = my-server.de
  }
```

When I run this application I get the following output:

**UPDATED: New console output after new jsch dependency 0.1.54**

```
INFO: Connecting to my-server.de port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'my-server.de' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic
INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
INFO: Disconnecting from my-server.de port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at kerberos.JschKerberos.main(JschKerberos.java:49)
```

Is there something incorrect with my configuration? Are there some conditions between the local (user, domain, etc.) and the remote one?

Comment: My 2 cents: to get all debug traces, add `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext` on the command line, to be sure that you don't miss any initialization setp

Comment: Also set `useTicketCache=false` and `storeKey=false` to make sure that you don't suffer from side effects from the cache. Since you provide the keytab to JAAS, you can keep your ticket private to your Java process.

Comment: Ok, I'll try later, thank you for the help so far. The jaas.conf and krb5.ini are ok or did I miss something?

Comment: The `java.security.debug` flags will show you *exactly* what Java thinks about your config...

Comment: I added also the second flag to my java code by "System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​‌​,logincontext");" (the first one I already had in the code). Still the same console output like above...

Comment: Setting that property via `System.setProperty()` might be to late. Try passing that as a parameter to the `java` binary (using `-D....`)

Comment: Ok, added the flags to the "java" command, still exact the same output.

Comment: changed the jsch version to the newest (0.1.54), now getting a longer console output, see in the question section above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution! It was a missing service keytab for the `sshd` service! Some service principals aren't generated automatically by the Kerberos server. So this has to been done manually by the kadmin, as the `sshd` service also has to authenticate against Kerberos! This is done by the `host/fqdn@REALM` principal.

**Important here: The "host" is a fixed String(!), I always replaced it by the hostname of my OpenSSH server machine... So, only "fqdn" and "REALM.COM" must be replaced by your data!**

- See this for more information (in German): http://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.3/opensuse-manual_de/manual/sec.kerbadmin.hostprinc.html
- This also shows the steps (English): http://www.microhowto.info/howto/create_a_host_principal_using_mit_kerberos.html

So these were the necessary steps for me to get the application work:

1. Set `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` config file of the OpenSSH server
2. Set `Host * [...] GSSAPIAuthentication yes` in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_conf` config file of the ssh client
3. Check the `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf` (or `.ini`) files on the client for correct settings (see the code blocks in the question section above)
4. On the Kerberos server, open `kadmin.local` and type `ktadd host/my-server.de`
5. optional: Add a user principal (if not exists yet): `ktadd keytabuser`
6. Make a `kinit keytabuser` (with password) or `kinit -kt /path/to/file.keytab keytabuser` (normal Kerberos command)
7. Check if the user is authenticated via `klist`
8. Run the application or ssh directly via console `ssh keytabuser@my-server.de`
9. You should be logged in by the cached ticket!

Of course, the user `keytabuser` must be a user on the ssh-server machine!

Comment: Duh. So you tried Kerberos auth in SSH, without first binding *globally* your Linux server auth to Kerberos (via `sssd` and the default `/etc/krb5.keytab`). And you did not know about Kerberos SPN (Service Principal Name) syntax. Looks like you got to a result against all odds, congratulations...